# Physics objects 'drifting' when making continuous contact

Tags: c#, game-physics

I've been trying to make a simple 3D physics engine as an exercise. My problem is that objects 'drift' when in contact with another object if their positions aren't perfectly aligned.

In my test case, the top box has physics enabled and is affected by gravity. The bottom box is static (its velocities are fixed at 0). If top box is positioned perfectly above the bottom box's center (so they share the same X and Z coordinates), the top box lands on the bottom and stays perfectly still. However, if the top box is offset on either the X or Z axis by event a little bit, it starts gaining momentum in that direction after it lands until it eventually falls of, as can be seen [here](https://youtu.be/4nRladBZEWI).

I know what causes this: when landing perfectly centered, the contact point supplied by EPA (which I've implemented based on [this](http://hacktank.net/blog/?p=119)) is positioned right below the top box's center. This causes the part of the jacobian that dictates the constraint torque to be applied to the top box (*r1 x normal*) to be 0. However, when offset, the contact point isn't directly underneath the top box's center anymore, causing it to rotate slightly. This in turn causes the contact normal on the next timestep to be rotated slightly. The top box is pushed out along this contact normal, causing it to slide around. I've confirmed this, as either disabling rotation or hard-coding to contact normal to 0,-1,0 fixes the issue.

I thought that implementing contact caching would fix this, but it doesn't as you can see in the video above, where each purple point represents an active contact. I am caching contacts over multiple time steps, and whenever a contact applies forces to an object it updates the penetration depth of all contacts involved with that object (including itself):

```
private void ApplyForces(RigidBody Body, Time deltaTime, vec3 deltaVel, vec3 deltaRot)
{
    Body.ForcesConstraints += deltaVel;
    Body.TorqueConstraints += deltaRot;

    foreach (Constraint c in M.InvolvedConstraints)
        c.UpdateConstraint(Body, deltaTime, deltaVel, deltaRot);
}

public override void UpdateConstraint(RigidBody Body, Time deltaTime, vec3 deltaVel, vec3 deltaRot)
{
    //I understand that this way of computing the actual positional delta the deltaRot represents is incredibly bad, but I coulnd't get anything else to work (I'm a linear algebra newbie).
    var rot = (quat.FromAxisAngle((deltaTime * deltaRot).Length, deltaRot.NormalizedSafe) * contact) - contact;

    var deltaPos = (deltaVel * deltaTime) + rot;
    
    //The contact normal points from Body1 to Body2
    _pendepth += (Body == Body1 ? 1 : -1) * vec3.Dot(deltaPos, _normal);
}
```

You can find my code [here](https://github.com/Etny/Yahtzee-Quest/tree/master/Game/Physics) (it's choas, I'm sorry).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly due to very small numbers making a difference over time. The sliding is quite minor. I cloned your repo, but I don't have the libraries to get it to run, so the only advice I can give you is just by reading the code.

However stuff like this makes me really nervous when I look at code:

```
 int index = -1;
 float maxDot = -9999;
 float td = -9999;
 float ti = -1;
```

I know what you are trying to do, but this sort of thing has led to a lot of very hard to find bugs for me in the past.

As for your Jacoabian problem, if I remember my physics correctly, a when a Jacobian is 0, that is a singularity, and your control forces cannot move it at all.

It definitely seems like you assume does indeed arise from very small angles between surfaces. My best idea is that if two surfaces are almost parallel (so the delta-angle is below some threshold, then you can disable some part of that physics process. This would probably involve "snapping" the object into to stable state that you describe where they exactly line up.

so:

```
public static float MinAngleThreshold = 0.001f;
        public override void UpdateConstraint(RigidBody Body, Time deltaTime, vec3 deltaVel, vec3 deltaRot)
        {
            //I understand that this way of computing the actual positional delta the deltaRot represents is incredibly bad, but I coulnd't get anything else to work (I'm a linear algebra newbie).
            var rot = (quat.FromAxisAngle((deltaTime * deltaRot).Length, deltaRot.NormalizedSafe) * contact) - contact;

            if(rot < MinAngleThreshold)
            {
                //do something here, potentially just return without updating. 
            }

            var deltaPos = (deltaVel * deltaTime) + rot;
            
            //The contact normal points from Body1 to Body2
            _pendepth += (Body == Body1 ? 1 : -1) * vec3.Dot(deltaPos, _normal);
        }
```

While there certainly are some problems with your code, the overall system is quite clever and you should be proud of what you've written.

Comment: I have implemented something akin to you suggestion. Rigidbodies store constraint torque under a certain threshold in a variable over multiple timesteps. The variable is decreased very significantly every timestep. If it or the constraint torque of a timestep gets over the threshold, it is added to the angular velocity and set to zero. This makes it so that bodies have to receive a certain amount of torque/second before it starts applying. It's a bit botchy, but it works. Thanks for your help! (Also thanks for the comment at the end. It really means a lot to me)

Comment: Advice isn't really an answer.  That belongs in comments.